# Yarn 2/3 link via resolution for local development breaks staging

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json, yarnpkg-v2, yarnpkg-v3

Just upgraded from Yarn 1 to Yarn 3.

In my `package.json` of my "Project 1" I have a dependencies to my published package

```
dependencies: {
  ...
  "@my-package/name": "3.4"
  ...
}
```

With Yarn 1 not altering `package.json` when [linking](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link#search)  "Project 1" to "@my-package/name" for local development, that worked fine.

[Linking my local version of the package with Yarn 2/3](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/link), it now added

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@my-package/name": "portal:../name"
  }
```

This breaks the build process during deployment on staging/production environments. That link is only meant for local development, while on other environments it should be ignored and (only) the published package above should be used.
Any idea if / how this is now possible?

Here is the ticket on that issue/change https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/90

Answer (score 3):

In yarn 3, I tried:

```bash
yarn link ~/local/package/path
```

It added:

```json
"resolutions": {
  "@namespace/package": "portal:/home/src/repo/local/package/path"
}
```

was working for me to deploy in staging env for testing. (Note: *We have different setup for prod*)